# text-align: justify — second line

Tags: css, center, text-align, justify

I want a text to be justified inside a div.
When the line breaks, I would love to have the second line (shorter) to be centered. Now the first line is justified, the second is aligned left.

Any ideas?

CSS:

```
.credits
{
opacity:.2;
text-align:justify;
font-size:18px;
line-height:21px;
}
```

Comment: What does your CSS look like at the moment?

Comment: @TimWilkinson, see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your second line is the last line, then you can use [`text-align-last`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last):

```
.credits {
    opacity: .2;
    text-align: justify;
    text-align-last: center;
    -moz-text-align-last: center; /* Firefox needs a prefix, according to the docs */
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 21px;
}
```

Warning: This is neither supported in Safari (mobile) nor Opera.

Comment: thanks mate! It works perfect. That class is hidden on mobile and I guess not many of my visitors use Opera ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using CSS ::first-line Selector.

```
    p {
       width: 100px;
       text-align: center;
    }
    p:first-line {
       text-align:justify;
    }
```

Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wopp1n3/2/)